# input and output shape in convulational neural network

Tags: python, image

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_30 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, None, None]
```

Comment: What is your question? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the details that you have provided is very less. From the details that you have provided, I have interpreted that you are trying to pass a `numpy array` of dimension 3 to a `CNN Layer`. A `CNN Layer` only accepts `4-dimensional numpy arrays`, but you have given a `3-dimensional numpy array` as the input. In order to solve this problem, reshape the array to a 4D array. If you provide ur code, I will be able to provide you the exact lines that you have to use.